# Access parent controller n levels higher

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angular-controller

I have a page controller, simplified here

```
angular.module('app').controller('MyCtrl', function () {
    this.name = 'David'
});
```

I'm using the controllerAs syntax in my template (MyCtrl as main) so I just use **main.name** in my template to access the name. All good.

In my template I have a bunch of nested directives which create new scopes and somewhere at the bottom I have an **ng=controller="SubCtrl as subController"**. I can now access properties on the sub controller by doing **subcontroller.property** and within that template I can still access **main.name** because controllerAs is awesome.

The trouble is that in my second controller code I need to access things in the parent controller, which by this point is n levels deep. I know I can do this like this in the main controller...

```
$scope.main = this;
```

and then doing this in the second controller

```
var main = $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.main;
```

but we all know we shouldn't do that and I won't know how many levels deep it is anyway because I won't know how many directives the developer has placed it inside that create a new scope.

I hear some people talking about creating a service for this but that sounds like it would be difficult to do generically and I don't want the users of my framework to have to create a service every time they put an include inside a tab panel, that would be crazy.

So, my current idea is to use scopes and write a function which will traverse up parent scopes until it finds the scope you specify using a comparison function. I feel there might be a better way though.

Comment: Who the hell votes down a question without exposing what's wrong with it? I thought I explained it fairly well and it's a perfectly valid question.

Comment: so why not create a service? A service is a great place to store data or access to something that is needed across more than one controller,directive,factory,whatever. Its basically a singleton, you inject in in multiple places but its always the same instance getting injected. It is very easy to use and much less brittle than what you have in mind ($parent.$parent.n.....data). It is also much more testable if you are doing your unit tests.

Comment: I've been there, and I guarantee you that there's nothing better than a service if you want to share information between controllers. E.g: a service for storing info on the user `infoService`. The `mainCtrl` could do `infoService.registerUser({name : 'David'})` and then the `subCtrl` could do `infoService.getLatestUser()`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand. I don't just have one controller which I need to access from a nested child controller, I have them all over the all app and they access different parents. I actually need access to the methods and data of the controller (everything attached to "this" in the controller), so would I need to create a new service for every scenario I want to do this? I think that the fact it is a singleton is the problem?

Comment: You made it sound like it was just a piece(s) of data. Yes, you should still abstract the shared business logic into either factories (if there is no sharing of state) or into services (if there is sharing of state) and then inject them into your controllers when/where necessary. Keep everything is modular as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So why not create a service? A service is a great place to store data or access to something that is needed across more than one controller, directive, factory, whatever. Its basically a singleton, you inject in in multiple places but its always the same instance getting injected and is only created the first time it is needed. It is very easy to use and much less brittle than what you have in mind `($parent.$parent.n.....data)`. It is also much more testable if you are doing your unit tests.

```
var module = angular.module('app');

module.service('commonService', function () {
    this.sharedData = {name: ''};
});

// assume this gets loaded first
module.controller('MyCtrl1', ['commonService', function (commonService) {
    commonService.sharedData.name = 'David'
}]);

// and this is loaded somewhere after MyCtrl2
module.controller('MyCtrl2', ['commonService', function (commonService) {
    var name = commonService.sharedData.name;
}]);
```

*i have not validated the syntax but this is the basic structure, very simple.*

Comment: OK, so would I need to do this every time I have a grand-grand-parent > child scenario (literally ever page in my app that has a tab system) or would I be able to store them all on the service, e.g. the service could have a map of key value pairs where each key is a unique controller name and each value is a reference to a controller instance?

Comment: @jonhobbs - a service is nothing more than an object created only once so it could have anything you wanted to including references to controllers. As an OOP rule though the less types know about each other the more flexible the program is so `loose coupling` is always recommended. I would abstract the common/shared state and common/shared business logic into one or more services (or factories if there is no shared state), this is the best way for controllers to "communicate" between each other.